# Why is Heroku not binding to port of Java HTTP server?

Tags: heroku

I have implemented a basic HTTP server in java which I am trying to deploy to Heroku. The server behaves as expected when run on localhost, but on Heroku I get the following error in my logs:

```
2018-12-18T09:03:28.323430+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-12-18T09:03:32.152747+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java -jar build/http-server.jar`
2018-12-18T09:03:34.496251+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2018-12-18T09:03:34.517683+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -XX:+UseContainerSupport -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2018-12-18T09:05:02.493578+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-12-18T09:05:02.344933+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch
2018-12-18T09:05:02.344933+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2018-12-18T09:05:02.475449+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
```

I have set the `PORT` environment variable to `5000`, which is what my server is currently binding to (yes, it's hard coded for now). If I change the server port to `80`, for example, I can see in my logs that the server is unable to bind to that port, so I'm happy that it is binding to the correct port. My understanding of [the docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/setting-the-http-port-for-java-applications) is that I should just be able to set the port number that I need using the `PORT` environment variable.

Why, then, is Heroku unable to bind to this port? Is there some other action I should be taking, i.e. proxying from 443 to 5000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have set the `PORT` environment variable to `5000`, which is what my server is currently binding to (yes, it's hard coded for now).

You've got this backwards.

[The `PORT` environment variable is set by Heroku and your code must bind to that value](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#web-dynos). You can't hard-code the port, or choose it yourself. You must take it from the environment.

Comment: So I can't set `$PORT`?

Comment: No. Heroku sets `$PORT`. You must _use_ it. The documentation you referenced shows how to do that for a few common Java web servers.

Comment: Ah, okay. I didn't get that from the docs so thanks for clarifying.